# I want to be an airline pilot. Would becoming a NON-COMBAT Air Force pilot be a good way to become one?

Tags: airline-pilot, us-air-force

I know that becoming a fighter pilot is highly competitive, making it a difficult route, but would becoming a pilot for an Air Force cargo aircraft or something of the like be a good way to reach my final goal of piloting for an airline?

Comment: It's one way but not the only way.

Comment: Matters not whether you were flying a fighter or a transport or tanker or even a trainer like the T-6.  The airlines see the hours gained over several years in the Air Force as both highly valuable and highly desirable, regardless of what one has been flying.

Answer (score -3):

It depends on which part of the world you're in.

Airlines based in a country with a healthy General Aviation scene will probably prefer civil pilots. If there General Aviation scene is limited then it would make military pilots an attractive source.

I'm not saying that Military pilots are any worse/better but there have been airlines where the safety record was quite poor as a result of poor CRM from the military pilots, China Airlines and Korean Air are examples. These airlines have recognised and rectified the problems and today are up to industry levels in terms of accidents/incidents.

Comment: This isn't true.  Mil pilots are awesome at following procedures and are more of a "known quantity" to airlines.  A fighter pilot, for example, may have fewer hours and less experience in certain areas (like really bad weather, icing, IMC, etc), but that really doesn't matter since most of what they need to know can be trained in relatively easily.  On the other hand, a civil pilot with a varied background and twice the hours may have bad habits that are tougher to train away.  Which pilot is "best?"  Who knows...and it depends on the type of flying being done.